# Availability of older Metal Feature Set Table documents?

Tags: metal

Does anyone know of the availability of older versions of Apple's [Metal Feature Set Table](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables.pdf) document?

The current Metal 3.0 document references only the beta `MTLGPUFamily` and `MTLSoftwareVersion` enums...and does not document the older `MTLFeatureSet` enum...which is needed to determine runtime feature availability on devices running current and earlier macOS and iOS versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the Metal Feature Set Tables for [2017](http://d2jaiao3zdxbzm.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables-2017.pdf) and [2018](http://d2jaiao3zdxbzm.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables-2018.pdf) are no longer hosted by Apple.

Comment: Thanks! Much obliged.